# How use file for $template cache?

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I need use template from html file.

So I added script where the id is path to my html file.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/directives/userAvatarTooltip.html"><script>
```

and get template

```
var template = $templateCache.get('app/directives/userAvatarTooltip.html');
return template;
```

but template is empty.

p.s If I add template inside script tag it is works.

Comment: do you want it in directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var clone = $compile($templateCache.get("app/directives/userAvatarTooltip.html"));
    return $scope.$apply(function () {
        return clone($scope);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding via the $templateCache service:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

To retrieve the template later, simply use it in your HTML:

```
<div ng-include=" 'templateId.html' "></div>
```

or get it via Javascript:

```
$templateCache.get('templateId.html')
```